# Does there exist a circular sequence of equilateral right triangular prisms that "intersect nicely"?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Let **P** denote a compact 3D right prism in ℝ<sup>3</sup> that is the geometrical cartesian product of a 2D closed equilateral triangle of side = 1 and a closed unit interval.

Say that congruent copies **P**', **P**'' of **P** in ℝ<sup>3</sup> *intersect nicely* if both

a) their intersection is along a common square face, and

b) they are rotated 90º with respect to one another.

(For the union **U** of two congruent copies of **P** that intersect nicely, the union of the five squares in **U** is homeomorphic to a torus with an open disk removed.)

*Questions*:

1. Does there exist a positive integer n and a family {**P**<sub>j</sub> ⊂ ℝ<sup>3</sup>  | j ∈ ℤ/nℤ} of congruent copies of **P** such that (taking index arithmetic mod n)

a) for all indices j, j+1 ∈ ℤ/nℤ the prisms **P**<sub>j</sub>, **P**<sub>j+1</sub> intersect nicely, and

b) for indices j, k ∈ ℤ/nℤ with |j-k| ≥ 4 we have **P**<sub>j</sub> ∩ **P**<sub>k</sub>  =  ∅ ?

(It is easy to see that any such n must satisfy n ≥ 4.)

2. If there does exist such a circular sequence of **P**'s, must n necessarily be even?
3. If there does exist such a circular sequence of **P**'s, what is the smallest n for which it exists?

Edit: I originally thought that |j-k| ≥ 3 implying no intersection was feasible, but it is not. So condition b) now reads |j-k| ≥ 4, which is.

Comment: Thinking more after my failed attempt a couple days ago. Maybe I'm missing something, but is there actually more than one way to assemble these?   It seems to me that for the first few prisms we add we have a choice, but those choices are all the same up to symmetry.  Then once we get to the fifth prism and onward it looks to me like there is only one place to put it.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** This is not quite right (see comments), but I'll leave it up in case it can be fixed.

Suppose we have such a circular sequence with $n$ prisms. Let's ignore the geometry and just count faces, edges and vertices:

**Faces:** Each prism has three of its faces left exposed at the end, 5 minus the two where it meets its neighbors.  $F = 3n$

**Edges:**  Lets count them as we add the prisms one by one.  The first prism contributes 9 edges. Each new one after that contributes 5 new edges (9 minus the four of the square we are gluing along), until the last one which only contributes 2 new edges (the two edges that are not a part of the 2 square faces we glue it along). $E = 9 + 5(n-2) +2 = 5n+1$

**Problem 1:** When we glue the *second* to last prism to make the "hole" into which the last prism fits, an additional edge is occluded so that prism contributes only four edges not five. The additional occluded edge is opposite the last externally exposed square face that appears when the final prism is added. So the edge count drops to $5n$.

**Vertices:** Same strategy as for edges.  The first prism gives $6$ new vertices, each one after that contributes 2 new ones (6 minus the 4 on the face being glued), except for the last one which contributes no new vertices.  $V = 6 + 2(n-2) = 2n+2$

**Problem 2:** Basically the same as Problem 1. The additional occluded edge whwn we put in the penultimate prism also implies two additional occluded vertices, dropping the final count to $3n$.

But then $V-E+F = (2n+2)-(5n+1)+3n = 1$, but genus 1 union of polyhedra has $V-E+F = 0$.

**No longer.** With the corrections noted, the Euler characteristic becomes $3n-5n+2n=0$ and the claimed contradiction does not in fact occur. Sorry it had to work that way.

Comment: Beautiful and elegant. I could not tear my mind away from the geometry, which I found confusing.

Comment: And yet something is gnawing at me: The proof does not seem to make any use of the 90º rotation between prisms sharing a square face. Yet if we omit rule b) and instead always avoid making any 90º rotation, then it is easy to arrange, say, 12 prisms with a triangular hole in the middle, or 18 prisms with a hexagonal hole, such that the boundary of their union is homeomorphic to a torus, so has Euler characteristic equal to 0.

Comment: The problem here is, I think, that given a circular sequence of n prisms {**P**_j  ⊂ ℝ^3  |  j ∈ ℤ/nℤ}, then for any indices j, k with |j-k| ≤ 3 (mod n),  we have **P**_j ∩ **P**_k  ≠ ∅, and this must be taken into account when calculating the Euler characteristic.

Comment: Yea I agree there is an issue here.  If we look at those examples and try to go though my argument the face count is fine, but the edge and vertex counts are off because when they go around the loop they reconnect earlier than I accounted for. Still I'm curious if this can be salvaged using the geometric constraint.